Alpine 3D 3 CD changer magazines, 3D print plans?
I have a old Alpine head unit 7983r that uses Alpine 3D shuttle magazines. (Alpine model 4907). They are hard to come by, or expensive. They have been used in Volvo cars too at early 2000s, maybe other makers too. Is there a plans to 3D print the magazine, or is it feasible?

More or less a standard answer for me is to suggest that you make a post on the subreddit for this sort of request:
https://www.reddit.com/r/3Drequests
Within, you can post images (recommended) and request a design for a 3D print. Sometimes the designer will print the item, other times, design only, which then requires a visit to the subreddit for that purpose:
https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprintmything
The advantage of using the subreddits is that many eyes with correct qualifications will see your request and will also be able to reply, either publicly or privately.

That is very informative answer. Too bad i cannot dismantle the one and only one magazine i own, have to find second one to break a part. There is no seams on one, fully enclosed plastic.

@Petri-fied If that is true, it will probably do not print well, maybe only on a resin printer
